# Set source for the image object - Dashcode related

Tags: javascript, dashcode

How can one change the source of an image object in Dashcode (Javascript) at runtime?

I tried:

var image = document.getElementById("image").object;
image.src = "IMG_0230.JPG";

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an image in a list view and I've set up a value transformer for that image that takes the name of the image file stored in the datasource and prepends a URL path to load the file from the server it resides on.

Is this similar to what you're trying to do? If so, then there is a section on Value Transformers in the DashCode doc. It's one of the few things that is documented! :)

Comment: Great, thank you. This would be my next task. I found the image.setSrc() function which helped. But this is more elegant.

Answer (score 3):

I got this to work
I made sure that the image was stored in the Images folder of the project

```
var image = document.getElementById("image");
image.firstElementChild.src = "image source";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the point of `.object` is, the reference should be enough. Is there an `object` property?

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I had to be more specific. I used the Image Element from the Library in Dashcode. The image is loaded if I enter the URL or place of the image into the element inspector. My question is, how I can change the source (the image) on runtime.

Comment: I got it! After digging into the core part of ImageView I found the function: image.setSrc(<URL>);

Answer (score 0):

`image.setSrc` function is not working for me.

I found another way to solve the problem -

```
document.getElementById("imageView").innerHTML = '<img id="DC_img" 
    class="apple-hidden" apple-group="image" src="' + url + '">';
```

The Image Part of Dashcode creates a div block and inside it it creates img tag that contains source as attribute. So, either write the `innerHTML` for `imageView` or find the img tag with its ID and use `setAttribute()` function.

Answer (score 0):

I always use this

```
var image = document.getElementById("imagetobeset");
image.firstElementChild.src = "imagefile";
```

Where **imagetobeset** is the name of the element you want to change and 
**imagefile** is the name of the file you want your image source to be set to.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try this, it will work

```
document.getElementById("image").src="fineName.jpg";
```